# Service Unavailable (503) No TypoScript template found

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I tried to install the introduction package in Typo3 cms.

But I receive the following error:

> Service Unavailable (503) No TypoScript template found!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include the package into your core template in Typo3.

Whenever you are using a new package/extension which having template files, you are needed to added those in your root template.

1. Go to Template Menu in the typo3 backend
2. Select the root page from the treelist on the left side panel (it might be Congratulations).
3. Choose the info/modify from the top list
4. click on Edit the whole template record button.
5. Choose the includeTab
6. Add the package related to it.

Comment: Iam getting this error after completing the above steps."Oops, an error occurred!
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS Field, COLUMN_TYPE AS Type, IS_NULLABLE AS `Null`, COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS Extra, COLUMN_COMMENT AS Comment, CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS CharacterSet, COLLATION_NAME AS Collation FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'typo3_src' AND TABLE_NAME = 'sys_template'': Table 'C:\xampp7.3\tmp\#sql3484_1f3_0.MAI' is read only"

Comment: Did you check if your projects folder having appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yes  folders have permissions