# Create first page in Typo3

Tags: typo3

I am totally new in Typo3, but fine with PHP and Apache. I have just installed Wamp 3.3.2 and Typo3 13.0.1. I created a new page and trying to display it showed me `Service Unavailable (503) No TypoScript template found`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638232/service-unavailable-503-no-typoscript-template-found) post, but I don't have the template menu. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162156/typo3-v12-4-500-page-not-found-the-page-did-not-exist-or-was-inaccessible-rea), tried to follow the [tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-typoscript-in-45-minutes/main/en-us/TypoScriptOverview/TheTermTemplate/Index.html), the error says:

```
throw new InternalServerErrorException($message, 1607585445);

(1/1) #1607585445 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\InternalServerErrorException
No TypoScript record found!
```

I wanted to try to fix it followings, but don't understand where to put it:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = Hello World
```

Could someone tell me how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [TYPO3 Sitepackage Tutorial](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/main/en-us/Index.html) - especially the videos linked in there to see where tk access TypoScript templates.

However, I would recommend two things to get started here:

1. Check out the "[bootstrap package](https://www.bootstrap-package.com/)" as an extension to TYPO3. It gives you a fully working frontend you can go with
2. TYPO3 v13 is in its early sprint releases and not yet ready for "prime time" as many extensions are not yet compatible. You might be better off using v12 for now.
   The mentioned bootstrap package actually might work with v13 in its current dev-main state, but it definitenly works in v12.

The learning curve sadly is very steep, but once you graps the concepts, it gets very powerful. Let us know how you advance :)

Comment: I understand. I think I will move to Wordpress or create one by myself, based on my customer needs.